# Clearing bound checkboxes on a subform in access

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba

i have a form with a subform query on it. The subform query has a row of checkboxes (bound to the table) for users to select multiple items. When the users press a command button another query is run to search for all checkboxes that are marked true and then open another form. I am trying to make it so that when another command button is pressed, all of the checkbox values on the subform query change to false. So far the code that i am using only changes the last selected checkbox to false. How do I get it to change all of the values to false?

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.SuppliesQuerySubform.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Value <> False Then
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Update the records using SQL. Something like `UPDATE tblItems SET IsSelected = FALSE WHERE ...` (*Replace tblItems with your table and IsSelected with the field the checkbox is bound to.*) Then you should refresh your subform with `.Requery`

2) Use `RecordsetClone`. This is actually a copy of the records shown in your subform which you can loop through and update.

```
With Me.RecordSetClone
   .MoveFirst
   Do While .Eof = false
      .Edit
      .Fields("IsSelected") = FALSE
      .Update
      .MoveNext
   Loop
End With
```

Comment: When I use the recordsetClone option I get the following run-time error 7951: "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the RecordsetClone property."   I haven't worked much with this so I'm not sure how to fix it.  The only thing I have changed in the above code is the .IsSelected was changed to my field name Select.

Comment: My mistake. Use `.Fields("IsSelected")` instead. I will fix it in the main answer

Comment: It still gives me the same error. When I click Debug it has the first line highlighted.

Comment: I have it in the OnClose of the form. I think i fixed that issue (not sure really) but now it gives me another error.  Run-time error 3020 "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit". 'With Me.SuppliesQuerySubform.Form.RecordsetClone
   .MoveFirst
   Do While .EOF = False
      .Fields("Select") = False
      .Update
      .MoveNext
   Loop
End With'

Comment: Add `.Edit` . I will fix it in main answer

Comment: You should run this code in the `Click` event of the command button not in the `Close` event

Comment: You are freaking AWESOME!!! I have been stuck on this for weeks and I am new to some of this so I have been at a loss. Your code worked exactly how I need it to. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.